# In Normal Mode How Can I Boost My Instinct?

Tags: hitman-absolution

In Hitman:Absolution, I am currently playing the mission Part 1: Terminus. I am playing in Normal mode. AFAIK Normal mode does not regenerate Instinct. I have to rely on other sources for that. In my campaign I am real low on Instinct. How can I boost it, to get past guards and to Room 899?

Comment: If you want to get to Room 899, perhaps tell where you start from on that level (outside the window, etc) as they can change how you get to the room. But if the question is about getting more instinct in general, that's a slightly different question and the red herring about 899 should probably be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A usual and practical way to restore Instinct is by finding a nearby NPC to kill/knockout silently *and* then hiding their bodies in a container. Check if there's a container nearby where you can safely hide a body before going in for the kill/knockout. Make sure the kill/knockout is silent.

You can also gain Instinct by "hiding". This can be done by pressing the "hide" button when a prompt comes up near an object where you can hide.
<sup>([Thanks to Ben for mentioning.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94494/in-normal-mode-how-can-i-boost-my-instinct/95691#comment132438_95691))</sup>
If you are in a position where you can collect evidence or achieve a mission objective, then you might want to go for those instead, as doing those will also restore Instinct.

To prevent Instinct from going down, avoid being noticed by NPCs wearing the same clothes as your disguise. Sneak/crouch whenever possible when around these NPCs; this will lessen the need for instinct mode.

Comment: @desaivv I'll update it as I find out more ways. Those are all I currently know. I usually do the 'kill/knockout and hide body' technique when I need to restore instinct. I don't really play this game as much as the other games that I give detailed answers for. Hence, the current not-so-detailed answer. =)

Comment: You can also gain instinct by "Hiding" (IE, hitting the "Hide" button when it gives you the option).